# Vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}$ and finite projective dimension

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

Does it follow from "for all finitely generated $N$, there exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0, \mathrm{Ext}^n(M,N)=0$" that $M$ has finite projective dimension, for a finitely generated $M$ ?

What if the ring $R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, for a certain field $k$ ? If it's $kG$, for a finite group $G$ ? If it's $kG$, and I'm also assuming $\mathrm{Ext}^n(N,M)=0$ for $n$ large enough (how large still depending on $N$ though) ?

Of course, if $n_0$ doesn't depend on $N$ it's clearly the case; but I saw some paper which seems to claim that more general statement in the case of $kG$.

I know how to prove it when $G$ is a $p$-group and $\mathrm{char} k = p$, using a minimal projective resolution and the fact that any projective has a nonzero map to the simple module $k$; but I'm not sure that's true for more general $G$; and the paper is not very clear about whether $G$ is assumed to be a $p$-group or not, so I'd like to know how general the result is.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is true in general even if $n_0$ doesn't depend on $N$, because of the restriction that $N$ is finitely generated.  It would suffice if you also assumed $R$ is Noetherian, since then $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,-)$ preserves filtered colimits.

Comment: @EricWofsey : woops, it wasn't clear from what I wrote, but the case "$n_0$ doesn't depend on $N$" was meant for $kG$ for a general finite group $G$, and in this case $kG$ is clearly noetherian (I'm really mainly interested in $kG$, the rest was the hope that there would be a general solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true whenever $R$ is Artinian.  Indeed, in that case you can take $N$ to be a direct sum of all the simple modules up to isomorphism (there are only finitely many since all of them must appear in a composition series of $R$), and use the same argument as you used in the case that $G$ is a $p$-group.  Explicitly, take a minimal resolution of $M$ (projective covers exist since everything is Artinian).  Each map in this resolution has superfluous image, and thus vanishes when composed with any map to a simple module.  This means all the maps in the resolution become $0$ after Homming into $N$.  But each nontrivial term of the resolution has a nontrivial map to some simple module, and thus every term remains nonzero after Homming into $N$.  We thus find that $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,N)$ is nontrivial for all $n$ unless the resolution terminates, i.e. unless $M$ has finite projective dimension.

I believe it's also true when $R$ is Noetherian and commutative: if $R$ is local, the argument above still works since there is only one simple module and projective covers exist.  So, $M$ has finite projective dimension after localizing at any prime.  Then, since $M$ is finitely generated, if it has finite projective dimension locally at some prime, it has finite projective dimension in an entire Zariski neighborhood of that prime.  We can then cover $\operatorname{Spec} R$ by finitely many of these Zariski neighborhoods to conclude $M$ has finite projective dimension globally.

I doubt it's true over an arbitrary ring, but don't know a counterexample.

Comment: Is there an elementary way to see that there are only finitely many simple modules over $kG$ ? (by elementary I mean not relying on some theory of Artinian rings) Of course when $G$ is a $p$-group there's only one simple module, but how about more generally when $\mathrm{char} k \mid p $ ?

Comment: Oh wait the statement about Artinian rings is actually pretty elementary, right ? Let $S$ be a simple $R$-module, $f: R\to S$ an epi, and $K_0\leq ...\leq K_n$ a composition series for $R$, then take $i$ to be the minimum such that $f_{\mid K_i}$ is nonzero. Then $f: K_i\to S$ is surjective and zero on $K_{i-1}$ so that it passes to $K_i/K_{i-1}$ which is simple, therefore $S$ is isomorphic to $K_i/K_{i-1}$, right ?

Comment: (I had thought of a solution along these lines, but didn't get why $kG$ should only have finitely many simple modules, so thank you for pointing out that it's related to Artinian-ness, to the composition series more precsiely)

Comment: That's exactly right.